# MyEclipse not picking up PhoneGap?

Tags: myeclipse, phonegap-desktop-app

Why wont MyEclipse let me create a phonegap application? I have installed NodeJS first, then i installed PhoneGap and then i installed MyEclipse but still there is no option under the mobile tab?

I have tried repeatedly but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MyEclipse 2016 CI 0, the PhoneGap tooling is not there, so you won't be able to create a PhoneGap application. This removal was mentioned in the delivery log and also [on the forum](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/phonegap-tooling-in-myeclipse-2016/).

If you need PhoneGap tooling, you will have to go back to the 2015 release stream for now; there will be different mobile support in a later 2016 release.